# php sign in using cookie doesn't work

Tags: php, cookies

login.php:

```
include("database.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['AuthVal']))
       unset($_COOKIE['AuthVal']);

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
   $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
   $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

   $sel_user = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass'";
   $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

   $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);


   if($check_user > 0)
   {  
      // echo $_POST['username'];
      $cookie_name = 'username';
      $cookie_value = $_POST['username'];
      echo $cookie_name;
      echo $cookie_value;
      // echo $_COOKIE['username'];
      setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30)); 
      echo $_COOKIE['username'];
      // echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
   }
   else 
   {
      echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again')</script>";
   }
}

?>
```

database.php:

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'users');
   $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

So if you look at login.php my $cookie_name is 'username' and $cookie_value is the actual username when user types in to log in. When I print it to the page using echo, they print what is expected, but when I click log in button, it doesn't store any cookie into my development tool on chrome. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue? Thank you.

And my database table only has ID which is auto incremented, and username and password.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Check the `Set-Cookie` response headers if something is off.